# Do value-type extension methods provide write-access to the original value?

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, extension-methods, value-type

I'm writing extension methods for value-types (such as `int`) for some custom small-volume encoding and decoding algorithms.
There may be other designs that don't use extension methods, but I'm concerned this isn't the last time I'll be facing this problem, so I'd like to know how extension methods are expected to work with this type of design.

For example:

```
int i = 10;

string str = i.Encode(); // Convert 10 to an unpredictable string such as "tZh0Ao"

i = 5; // Overwrite i with a new value.

i.Decode(str); // Decrypt the string to reassign the original value of 10
```

I'm not sure how the `this` parameter works for value-type extension methods.
Is it just a copy of the original value?
Or does it work like a `ref` or `out` parameter, preserving changes made to the value of the parameter?

For example:

```
/* This method will decode a string,
   and assign the decoded value to 'this' int. */

public static void Decode(this int value, string str)
{
    int result;

    /* ... perform work with str to produce decoded value ... */

    value = result; // Assign the decoded value to 'this' int.

    /* If 'value' is just a copy of the original int,
       the assignment won't have any permanent effect. */
}
```

Comment: It's not passed by `ref`, so it will not update the original variable that you call it on.

Comment: You might want to check out [Value Types and Reference Types at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Comment: It would be much better to just make it return `int` instead.  `public static int Decode(string str)`.  So instead of `i.Decode(str);` it would be `i = Decode(str);`

Comment: There's also an interesting discussion about this on the MSDN forums; [Extension methods can't use 'ref' and 'this' at the same time?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b26eac53-6485-4789-8a6a-80552d08db52/extension-methods-cant-use-ref-and-this-at-the-same-time?forum=csharplanguage)

Comment: also read about Extension Methods in C# it's a good easy read - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/709310/Extension-Method-In-Csharp

Comment: @juharr what are you talking about ?

Comment: @MalteR Sorry, misread your comment, though you were suggesting out parameters.

Comment: In C# 7.2, you can use `this ref` in extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to know how extension methods are expected to work with this type of design.

They're not.

Extension methods were introduced in C# 3.0 in order to allow LINQ to find `.Select` and others for any `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` instance, without requiring each and every implementation of those interfaces to define the methods anew, and without breaking the large amounts of existing code that implemented `IEnumerable<T>` already.

Allowing this to work did not require allowing `this ref` extension methods. That doesn't mean such extension methods don't make sense, or that they wouldn't be useful, only that they were not considered when extension methods were created.

It's the same reason we don't have extension properties. Allowing extension properties was considered as part of WPF's attached properties, IIRC, but although they might make sense, they ultimately proved unnecessary for the intended goal, so were left out of the C# language.

If there is a compelling reason for `this ref` extension methods, propose it to the language designers. That's how any new language feature gets added. If no compelling reason is known yet, the extra work needed in modifying the compiler is generally a reason for not modifying the language.

> Is it just a copy of the original value?

Yes. All extension method invocations get translated by the compiler into the equivalent static method invocation. `i.ExtensionMethod();` and `ExtensionClass.ExtensionMethod(i);` do the same thing. If the latter cannot modify `i` (because it's not declared as `ref`), the former cannot either.

You won't find many mutating instance methods in the .NET Framework either. It's generally considered better to make instance methods return a new value, and let the caller worry about whether to assign it to the existing instance or a new one. Suppose `DateTime.AddDays` modified the instance it was called on (it's possible to design the type like that). Then the typical programmer won't understand why

```
public void AddOneDay(DateTime[] array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i].AddDays(1);
}
```

and

```
public void AddOneDay(List<DateTime> list) {
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    list[i].AddDays(1);
}
```

have radically different behaviour.

The same logic applies to your own instance methods: although the language does allow you to create mutating methods for your custom value types, they are generally best avoided to prevent user confusion.

If your situation is an exception, if in your situation it turns out that mutating methods make for a far better developer experience, then present your situation to the language developers.

But I think the typical user won't understand what your `i.Decode(str)` would do, if it were valid. A somewhat more typical design would be to create a

```
public static int Decode(this string str)
```

extension method, and use it as

```
i = str.Decode();
```

avoiding the problem altogether.

Comment: An answer worthy of Jon Skeet ❗️